# How can I get to the message data in ZMQ using C++?

Tags: c++, zeromq

Within C++ ZMQ, I'm having trouble printing ( or otherwise analyzing ) data, which is pushed to consumers.
In `Python` and `scala` it works great, but C++ the output is either null or some un-decodable junk.
[From official helper example](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/zhelpers.hpp):

```
//I added the printf line:
static std::string s_recv (zmq::socket_t & socket) {
    zmq::message_t message;
    socket.recv(&message);
    printf ("[-] Message: %s\n", (char*)message.data());
    return std::string(static_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size()); 
}
```

The following is the context of where **`s_recv`** is called from:

```
int main () {                              //  Official ZMQ Hello World example
    zmq::context_t context (1);            //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::socket_t socket ( context,
                           ZMQ_REP         //  REP-side of a REQ/REP pattern
                           );
    socket.bind ( "tcp://*:5555" );

    while (true) {
        zmq::message_t request;
                                           //  Wait for next request from client
     // socket.recv (&request);            //  commented out to treat as string
        s_recv(socket);                    //  added for same reason as above
        std::cout << "Received Hello" << std::endl;

        sleep(1);                          //  Do some 'work'

        zmq::message_t reply (5);          //  Send reply back to client
        memcpy ((void *) reply.data (), "World", 5);
        socket.send (reply);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
[-] Message: @
```

In my non-hello world code, I get output resembling some kind of encoding error, my terminal throws a bunch of "?".

How can I get to the messages in ZMQ using C++?

**Edit for more info:**

In my non-hello world code, I use **`PUSH / PULL`**, not a **`REQ / REP`**.

Sample pushing code, same problem with both code bases:

```
  ifstream file(filePath.c_str(), ios::in|ios::binary);
  file.read(&chunk_data[0], chunk_size);
  memcpy((void*)message.data(), &chunk_data[0], this_chunk_size);
  socket.send(message);
```

Output and binary garbage:

```
[-] Message: �_�z�
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the binary garbage that you're getting in hex form? Also, can you show the code of the application sending the request (the ZMQ_REQ side)? I have a hunch the two processes are using different string encoding schemes.

Comment: yep, thanks @chwarr. [hwclient](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/hwclient.cpp) and [hwserver](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/hwserver.cpp) are the codebases for the "@" output, lock stock and barrel from the examples.

Comment: This looks wrong: `(char*)message.data()`. You disable any type checking that the compiler would do for you, so I'm not surprised you get junk. Don't use C-style casts unless you have to. This isn't a place where you have to. BTW: Since you have sending and receiving implemented in other languages, you can swap these in to test their C++ counterparts in order to find out which side is causing the problems.

Comment: For the record, I just ported my code to C instead of C++ and it's working great.